# AVQueuePlayer stop playing in background after a period of time

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using this block of code to play music in background.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    }catch {
    }
}
```

After a song is played, my app will call an API to get next song to play. Everything is working fine. It means my application can stream music online. But after about 15-20 minutes, application stops playing music. If I go to my application, it works again. I do not know why.

I am really appreciated with any helps. Thank you.